# Mysql CASE statement with subquery in JPQL

Tags: java, jpql

In MySQL

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (t.code = 'ITEM') THEN (SELECT i.amount FROM Billable_Item i WHERE i.Billable_Item_id = ri.billable_Id) ELSE 0 END) FROM Reservation_Item ri JOIN RESERVATIoN r on r.RESERVATION_ID = ri.RESERVATION_ID JOIN billable_Type t on t.billable_Type_id = ri.billable_Type_id WHERE r.reservation_id = xxx
```

In Hibernate JPQL

```
@Query(
    "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (t.code = 'ITEM') THEN (SELECT i.amount FROM BillableItem i WHERE i.id = ri.billableId) ELSE 0 END) " +
    "FROM ReservationItem ri JOIN ri.reservation r JOIN ri.billableType t WHERE r.id = :reservationId")
```

above SQL statement work well in MySQL, however, when converted to Hibernate JPQL it hit an exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query [SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (t.code = 'ITEM') THEN (SELECT i.amount FROM com.flyt.domain.BillableItem i WHERE i.id = ri.billableId) ELSE 0 END) FROM com.flyt.domain.ReservationItem ri JOIN ri.reservation r JOIN ri.billableType t WHERE r.id = :reservationId]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:257)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:104)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:79)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:222)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:200)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1739)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-case-expressions) doesn't say that subqueries inside case are supported, so, given that and the exception you get, you can safely assume that this is just not valid HQL.